# In nonlinear regression, when is MLE equivalent to least squares regression?

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, least-squares, nonlinear-regression

I recently received this one line question in a job interview and was a little stumped by it.

> In nonlinear regression, when is Maximum Likelihood Estimation equivalent to least squares?

Comment: It seems like `[self-study]` question, so what is your response to this? What kind of hints would help you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By definition, the least squares estimator minimises the sum of the squared distances between the actual and predicted responses.  With a set of simple steps, you can show that this estimator is equivalent to the solution of a certain maximisation problem.  If we let $f$ denote the nonlinear regression function and let $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ denote the parameter of this function (and let $\sigma>0$ be an arbitrary scaling parameter), we then have:

$$\begin{align}
\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_\text{OLS}(\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{x})
&\equiv \underset{\boldsymbol{\beta}}{\text{arg min}}  \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - f(\mathbf{x}_i, \boldsymbol{\beta}))^2 \\[6pt]
&= \underset{\boldsymbol{\beta}}{\text{arg max}} \bigg( - \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - f(\mathbf{x}_i, \boldsymbol{\beta}))^2 \bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \underset{\boldsymbol{\beta}}{\text{arg max}} \bigg( - \frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - f(\mathbf{x}_i, \boldsymbol{\beta}))^2 \bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \underset{\boldsymbol{\beta}}{\text{arg max}} \ \exp \bigg( - \frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - f(\mathbf{x}_i, \boldsymbol{\beta}))^2 \bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \underset{\boldsymbol{\beta}}{\text{arg max}} \ \prod_{i=1}^n \exp \bigg( - \frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} (y_i - f(\mathbf{x}_i, \boldsymbol{\beta}))^2 \bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \underset{\boldsymbol{\beta}}{\text{arg max}} \ \prod_{i=1}^n \text{N} (y_i | f(\mathbf{x}_i, \boldsymbol{\beta}), \sigma^2). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

(These steps use the fact that the $\text{arg min}$ and $\text{arg max}$ are invariant/anti-variant to strictly monotonic transformations.  Look through the steps to ensure you understand why the minimising/maximising point is preserved under the steps.)  The latter estimator is an MLE for a certain nonlinear regression model form --- can you see what model form this is?

---

**Update:** Per the suggestion from [Dave](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/247274/) in comments below, now that this question is a year old we can give a full solution.  From the above equation we see that the MLE matches the least squares estimator when the regression model uses IID [normal (Gaussian)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) error terms.

Comment: What is N() meant to imply in the last step?... oh, the distribution type with standard deviation, sigma. I don't really get how one would interpret the second last line to be equivalent to the last line though. does "|" mean something different in this context from the standard x given y normally used in probability?

Comment: @Wesley: The value $y_i$ coming before the $|$ part is the *argument* of the density function (i.e., the outcome value whose density we are interested in).  This is standard notation when we use density functions.

Comment: Just isn't my field, but I can accept it. The second last line is mathematically clear to a pleb like me, the last line, jargon.

Comment: @Wesley: The notation on the last line is for the [normal density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).  If you have a look at the form of this density you will see that it is the same as the line above, except for a positive scaling constant.  (Also, for anyone outside of maths/stats, *everything* in the question and answer is jargon.)

Comment: @Wesley on the "$N$": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Notation

Comment: That it is a Normal or Gaussian distribution is clear to me, but the second last line, to me, is a normal distribution about a difference in two values, i.e., a normally distributed error, with a standard deviation dictated by $\sigma$. The last line should say the same thing, I just don't get how $y_i | f(x_i, \beta)$ means difference or error. I  interpret it as a normally distributed function with an expected value of $y_i$, given by function $f_i$, with the same std dev dictated by $\sigma$.  But obviously I am just out of my field, and when "|" is used, it means difference

Comment: So to summarise, my understanding:
1) you can rearrange (via monotonicity, negation, and exponent addition) this square loss minimisation to maximising the product of probabilities of the example labels (the probabilities are assigned by your model, given its learned parameters $\beta$ and an arbitrary $\sigma$)
2) in short, the two are equivalent when your model's errors are normal?

Comment: I'd like to accept this answer but want to double check I understand it first. Is my summary accurate? The main thing I'm still a little confused by is the reference to a "nonlinear regression model form" - are we modelling the data as Gaussian or simply assuming that model errors will be Gaussian?

Comment: @James: Model errors are Gaussian.

Comment: Very helpful answer. I was wondering why in DL models, which are inherently nonlinear it still makes sense to use MSE as loss for regression models. The assumption must be that errors are still normally distributed. This, of course, isn’t always the case. For example, in insurance claim frequency models we assume the target is Poisson distributed and so the errors are not normally distributed. Therefore, we would use Poisson deviance or loss instead of MSE.

Comment: @thecity2 That would make for an excellent question to post. // Ben: a year later, might it be reasonable to write explicitly that the equivalence is for IID Gaussian errors in order to close out the question?

Comment: @Dave: Good suggestion --- updated.

Comment: @Wesley: Sorry for late response to your previous notational query; I just noticed that I hadn't fully answered it.  The standard notational convention in this context is that $\text{N}(y|\mu,\sigma^2)$ refers to the normal density evaluated at the point $y$ with mean parameter $\mu$ and variance parameter $\sigma^2$.  So the $|$ here doesn't refer to a difference --- it just separates the argument in the density from the parameters.  It just turns out that the argument and mean parameter enter into the normal density via their squared difference.