What is the likelihood of a regression?
I understand linear regressions themselves have likelihoods.  Is this simply the likelihood of the error?  I thought it was the likelihood of the data for Y given X.  In other words, $Lik(Y$~$X)=Lik(Y|X)$ so that $$Lik((X,Y))=Lik(Y|X)Lik(X)=Lik(X|Y)Lik(Y)=(proportionality.constant)probability(X,Y).$$  In other words we could reconstruct the likelihood for the joint distribution.  But this appears to only be true if both X and Y come from identical distributions.  I think I have made a counterexample which shows it is not true when the two marginal distributions of X and Y are different.  I have implemented it in R code:
# create simple dataset
XData<-c(-0.402103,-4.628608,2.731303,-1.041853)
YData<-c(-2.1607852,-0.3150687,-2.1435201,-0.2779723)
# I know the distributions X and Y come from are
# multivariate normal as described by the following
# Variance-Covariance matrices
# XMat has off diagonal entries which are non-zero
XMat<-matrix(c(4,2,0,0,
               2,4,0,0,
               0,0,4,1,
               0,0,1,4),nrow=4,ncol=4)
# YMat has all zeros along non-diagonal entries.
YMat<-diag(4,nrow=4,ncol=4)
# First I will show that ln(Lik(Y~X))+ln(Lik(X))
# =ln(Lik(X~Y))+ln(Lik(Y))=ln(Lik(X,Y)) 
# is true when both matrices are the same 
# (in this case both have all zeros on
# off-diagonal entries).
XonYResultA<-lm(XData~YData)
logLik(XonYResultA)
#'log Lik.' -7.830222 (df=3)
YonXResultA<-lm(YData~XData)
#'log Lik.' -3.686896 (df=3)
Xnorm<-MASS::fitdistr(XData,"normal")
Ynorm<-MASS::fitdistr(YData,"normal")
logLik(Xnorm)
#'log Lik.' -9.519879 (df=2)
logLik(Ynorm)
#'log Lik.' -5.376553 (df=2)
# Thus, you can see
logLik(Xnorm)+logLik(YonXResultA)
#'log Lik.' -13.20678 (df=2)
logLik(Ynorm)+logLik(XonYResultA)
#'log Lik.' -13.20678 (df=2)
# Give equal likelihoods.
# But this is no longer true when I model X as coming from 
# a different distribution than Y:
##### First, in order to run the special regression with different
##### distributions, I need to find the correct mean values:
findXMean<-function(par){
  return(-mvtnorm::dmvnorm(XData-par[1],sigma=XMat,log=TRUE)) #negative ln(lik) because subplex minimizes function to find optimum.
}
subplexResult1<-subplex::subplex(par=c(1),fn=findXMean)
XMean<-subplexResult1$par
XlnLik<- -subplexResult1$value #-10.71792
findYMean<-function(par){
  return(-mvtnorm::dmvnorm(YData-par[1],sigma=YMat,log=TRUE)) #negative ln(lik) because subplex minimizes function to find optimum.
}
subplexResult2<-subplex::subplex(par=c(1),fn=findYMean)
YMean<-subplexResult2$par
YlnLik<- -subplexResult2$value #-6.878869
##### Now I can find the likelihoods of Y ~ X and X ~ Y:
#####
XDelta<-XData-XMean
YDelta<-YData-YMean
findYonX<-function(pars){
  beta=pars[1]; EVar<-pars[2]
  residuals<-YDelta-beta*XDelta
  return(-mvtnorm::dmvnorm(residuals,sigma=EVar*YMat,log=TRUE))
}
subplexResult3<-subplex::subplex(par=c(1,1),fn=findYonX)
LikYGivenX<- -subplexResult3$value #-3.695906
LikJointYonXPlusX<-LikYGivenX+XlnLik #-14.41383
findXonY<-function(pars){
  beta=pars[1]; EVar<-pars[2]
  residuals<-XDelta-beta*YDelta
  return(-mvtnorm::dmvnorm(residuals,sigma=EVar*XMat,log=TRUE))
}
subplexResult4<-subplex::subplex(par=c(1,1),fn=findXonY)
LikXGivenY<- -subplexResult4$value
LikJointXonYPlusY<-LikXGivenY+YlnLik #-13.90974 

So you can see in the code above that LikJointYonXPlusX and LikJointXonYPlusY give different values meaning they cannot both be representing the likelihood of the joint
data X and Y.
I suppose my question is did I implement the regression correctly by saying residuals<-YDelta-beta*XDelta and if I did, why then, is the likelihood of the regression equal to the likelihood of the dependent variable given the independent variable when the two distributions are the same, but not when the two distributions are different?
Thank you.

Because this question is predicated on some unusual formulations of regression, clearing up what a regression model is might be a good place to begin.  Perhaps https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148638 will help.

that was interesting to read thanks.  My regression may be "unusual" but it is supposed to come from equation 12 from https://www.le.ac.uk/users/dsgp1/COURSES/THIRDMET/MYLECTURES/1REGRESS.pdf  where Eqn. 12 says E(Y|X)=E(Y)+ Beta(X-E(X)).  So I derived my model: residuals=Y-[E(Y)+Beta(X-E(X)]  As for the unusual formulation related to the error having dependencies as specified in XMat above, I was thinking that is just a typical application of generalized least squares which allows for arbitrarily unusual error structures.  Is there a 3rd way in which my regression is unusual?

I do not fully understand your simulations. But at the end you use dmvnorm where the xdata are correlated. This leads to a different likelihood then when using a lm assuming independent data.

thanks. is there a way helpful way i can clarify the simulations?  the lm calls were just to show that when the two distributions of X and Y are assumed to be the same that lik(X,Y) actually does equal lik(X~Y)*lik(Y) and contrast that to the later simulations where I optimize lik(X~Y) where the change in X is parameterized by a different distribution and where it appears that lik(X,Y) does not equal Lik(X~Y)*lik(Y)

I'm trying to say not that your regression is unusual but rather that considerable confusion about what regression and likelihoods are seems to be expressed in this post, so I recommend continued reading about both topics.  In particular, distributions don't have likelihoods by themselves, nor do regressions.  Here's a top-voted post about likelihoods you might find useful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2641.

I've seen places that people do use AIC to compare regression models which makes me think regressions must have something akin to a likelihood that can be used to calculate AIC.  But I have not seen much discussion about when this apparent "likelihood" of the regression will or not will be equal to the likelihood of the dependent variable given the independent one.  From running code like that above (and more) it looks like Lik(regression of Y on X)Lik(X)=Lik(Y & X) exactly when X and Y come from identically shaped multivariate normal distributions X ~ N(mu1, Sig1), Y ~ N(mu2, paramSig1).

The likelihood arises not from a regression per se but from a particular probability model for the regression.  A standard formulation is that the joint distribution of the responses $y_i$ depends in a specified way on an unknown linear function of the associated explanatory variables $x_i$ (which needn't have any distribution at all) together with some other parameters.  That's usually expressed in a way in which one can immediately write down an expression for the likelihood.

R's lm default formulation for regression seems to give a likelihood which "equals" the conditional probability of Y given X (e.g. logLik(Xnorm)+logLik(YonXResultA)).  I have tried implementing a formulation (above) for the likelihood to mimic this equality property for my case where X and Y both come from known but different distributions.  Is this a lost cause (because an infinite number of joints can give the same marginals)?  If so why does it work in the special case when X and Y are from the same distribution and lm's formulation is used?

A quick search of this site for "OLS MLE regression" turns up an answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/566187.  Check out the other hits for more information or try the more general search for "OLS likelihood regression".
